# Ng -Style with Index

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have some cards that are created with ng-repeat.(with class thumbnail).What i want is to change background colour for each card.I use `ng-mouseenter` and it works.But all cards are affected from background colour effect.I could not use index property of ng-repeat.Only one card should be affected when mouse is in active.

```
<div class="thumbnail"  ng-style="venuescardColour" ng-mouseenter="changeVenuesColor($index,true)"  ng-mouseleave="changeVenuesColor($index,false)">


$scope.changeVenuesColor = function(loc,bool) {
        if(bool === true) {
              $scope.venuescardColour = {background: 'red'};
        } else if (bool === false) {
              $scope.venuescardColour = {background: 'white'}; 
        }
    };
```

Comment: use `ng-class` instead!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why won't you use simple css?

```
.thumbnail {
   background: white;
}
.thumbnail:hover {
   background: red;
}
```

Comment: I added it but it does not work.Should i delete ng-style directive and other directives?